# Queen's Jubilee Celebrations

Tags: field-recording, uk

Thought I'd just send out a request to any UK-based SSDs who might be thinking of recording the atmosphere of the Queen's Jubilee Celebrations this weekend. From what I've heard, there'll be street parties all over the country as well as the [Thames Pageant](http://www.visitlondon.com/events/detail/22357258-thames-diamond-jubilee-pageant), so it seems to be a good opportunity to capture some nice ambiances of an historic moment.

Please feel free to share your recordings in this thread!

Answer (score 1):

I'm attending a street party though the weather outlook isn't good so we may just end up with some British rain ambience and soggy bunting...

I'll give it a shot though and see what I get! Hopefully there won't be music playing too much so I get some decent and usable recordings :)

Comment: Yeah but, you're recording digital, so can't you just use a filter on the music?  I mean, that's the point in recording digital isn't it? ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same boat as Alan (geddit?) - was going to try and record some atmos but the weather forecast predicts rain all day. I'll keep my handheld on me just incase the weather lightens up though.

Cheers